# printing a div multiple times after Ajax result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm working on laravel and I have an HTML block which is given below

```
<div class="white-panel">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">
    <!-- Here comes the title -->
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have another file which is `index.blade.php` which makes a AJAX Jquery request and gets titles.

```
function loadTitle() {  
  $.ajax(
    {  
      url: '{{url}}/get-data',  
      type: 'get',
      datatype: 'json',
      data:
        {  
           in: in
        }
     })
     .done(function(data){
       data.forEach( function(index) {
         console.log(index)
       }
     }    
}
```

this AJAX request works fine and I can see titles in the console, what I want to do is to loop through the titles and add that HTML block, given in starting of the question and add the title inside h4 tag and append block to the body for each title.
**Output of console.log:**

```
title1
title2 
title3
title4
```

**NOTE:** Looping through jquery using foreach is easy but I am confused about the HTML block part.

Comment: Please add the data of the console and then also provide where you want to add html/

Comment: @SagarGautam done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a renderer function to avoid repeating code like so

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>A page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function renderTitleHtml(title) {
      var html = '';

      html += '<div class="white-panel">';
      html += '<div class="media-body">';
      html += '<h4 class="media-heading">';
      html += title;
      html += '</h4>';
      html += '</div>';
      html += '</div>';


      return html;
    }

    function loadTitle() {
      $.ajax({
          url: '{{url}}/get-data',
          type: 'get',
          datatype: 'json',
          data: { in: in
          }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            //assuming an array of titles is returned
            $(data).each(function(index, title) {
              var titleEl = $('<div></div>');
              titleEl.html(renderTitleHtml(title));
              $(body).append(titleEl);
            })
          }
        }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you explain how your function after .each is taking two artugments, what are they?

Comment: this will have a problem with readability in your html tags because you cannot use tabs and newlines while concatenating the html.